# Convert postgreSQL query into nestjs/sequelize query

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I wrote a working postgreSQL query but I can't figure out how to turn it into a query in the **style of**

```
this.moviesSchema.findAll({
  where: { ownerId: id }
  attributes: ['title', 'released', 'genre', 'director']
});
```

---

**And here's the request**

```
select count(*)
from "Movies"
where EXTRACT(MONTH FROM "createdAt")=EXTRACT(MONTH FROM now())
and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM "createdAt")=EXTRACT(YEAR FROM now())
and "ownerId" = 3;
```

I would be grateful for your help

Comment: Just use your query as raw.

Answer (score 0):

Most ORM libs cover basic and generic query logic. Once you're using database specific features you should consider using the ORM lib mechanism to execute your query raw.